# iOS | Simulating/Catching AdMob's adViewDidReceiveAd in UITests

Tags: ios, admob, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

My project has a AdMob Banner Ad which should be globally visible when it gets an ad successfully. A controller has bannerView and a container view which contains an UINavigationController.

BannerView is initially outside the controller. When adViewDidReceiveAd called, bannerView goes up inside the controller view, and container view shrinks.

Here is a simple explanation:

[image: Explanation]

Now, I want to create UITests for this but I don't know how to simulate/catch adViewDidReceiveAd and didFailToReceiveAdWithError delegate methods.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I don't know of a way to do this without network traffic that doesn't involve creating your own protocols and objects that wrap the GADAdView and its delegate (MockableAdView, maybe), so you can make a second mocked implementation that just fires off the events the way you like.

If you don't mind involving network requests, you can request banners using our test ad unit ID (see the [test ads guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads)) when you want them to pass, and a fake, garbage ad unit ID when you want them to fail and send didFailToReceiveAdWithError. The test ad unit ID should perform reliably enough to avoid making your test flaky.

Comment: .exists() function always return true for bannerView, even it is out of the window. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar Have you tried `isHittable()` instead?

Comment: I'm a bit busy with a quick-job. I will try, and will inform you asap. Thanks.